# Fail login using unity sdk

Tags: facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

version 4.3.6 and 5.0.3

I already have apps.facebook.com/ffstudio-dev. It is doing well.
And I was created apps.facebook.com/thailandtfm today.
But new app is not working.

```
private void SetInit()
{
   FbDebug.Log("SetInit");
   Debug.Log("[SetInit]" + FB.IsLoggedIn);
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
    {
        FbDebug.Log("Already logged in");
        OnLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

In this code, `FB.IsLoggedIn` value is different.
At apps.facebook.com/ffstudio-dev,
`FB.IsLoggedIn` is true. it is right.

At apps.facebook.com/thailandtfm,
`FB.IsLoggedIn` is false. it is problem.

Two apps are in the physically same machine and storage.
Also, apps setting is almost same.
Surely, AppID is appropriate setup. i am repeatedly confirmed.

What is the problem?
How do  I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two appIds and it means two apps do not share any login information. Users should login each apps separately.